# Android Webapp hide scrollbar?

Tags: css, android, webkit, web-applications

is there a way (through javascript/jquery/css) to hide the scrollbar in android's web browser? 
Can't seem to find any valid info online and things that work for Google Chrome (webkit engine, as well) don't seem to work for the Android's browser.

Thanks bunches

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever tried [overflow-x/y](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html) for hiding scrollbars?